# Angular Translate - How to addPart() with $urlLoader?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using `staticFilesLoader` with `partialLoader` wich is working really good! So the concept of `addPart(home)` method in `partialLoader` says that you do not need to load all the translate table.

Starting for that point. I'm gonna use a rest service now and my question is *How to send to the rest service the parameter for just retrieving me the table translate for my specific section*, in this example `home`.

**Source Code from angular translate**

```
function $translateUrlLoader($q, $http) {

  'use strict';

  return function (options) {

    if (!options || !options.url) {
      throw new Error('Couldn\'t use urlLoader since no url is given!');
    }

    var requestParams = {};

    requestParams[options.queryParameter || 'lang'] = options.key;

    return $http(angular.extend({
      url: options.url,
      params: requestParams,
      method: 'GET'
    }, options.$http))
      .then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
      }, function () {
        return $q.reject(options.key);
      });
  };
}
```

The code above doesn't have any extra parameter.

**NOTE**: Maybe in the specific case of `urlLoader` with `partialLoader` you should request all the table translate from the REST and only manage the `parts` in the frontend. Please tell me about this note if makes any sense.